# Routerstatesnapshot State.url is appending initial route when redireting to previous URL after login

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to implement a feature where if user tried to access a URL without logging in then I am redirecting the user to login page with returnURL by using AUTH GUARD and then redirecting user to that particular URL after successfully logging in (followed this tutorial - https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/08/angular-2-redirect-to-previous-url-after-login-with-auth-guard). But it is always appending my initial route to the returnUrl, for example if I tried to access localhost:4200/job/111 then it is redirecting to localhost:4200/auth/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard%2Fjob%2F111 and because of that my redirection is failing. Here are my routes:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'auth', canActivate: [HashGuard], loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
    {
      path: '',
      canActivate: [ AuthGuard],
      loadChildren: './modules/dashboard-v3/dashboard-v3.module#DashboardV3Module'
    },
    {
      path: 'mobile',
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      loadChildren: './modules/mobile/mobile.module#MobileModule'
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      redirectTo: 'error'
    },
    {
      path: 'error',
      canActivate: [HashGuard],
      loadChildren: './modules/error/error.module#ErrorModule'
    },
  ];
```

and my auth-guard code is like this,

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private storage: StorageService,
    private router: Router,
  ){ }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    console.log('auth guard called');
    if(this.storage.retrieveAccessToken() && this.storage.retrieveAuthToken()){
      return true;
    } else if(!state.url.match('auth') && !state.url.match('join')) {
      console.log('RouterStateSnapshot values', state);
      return this.router.navigate(['/auth/login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you want to access to a route like `job/111`, so in your guard you are in the second condition, `!state.url.match('auth') && !state.url.match('join')`, so you navigate to the `auth/login` route.

I think the problem is in your guard, you should do :

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    console.log('auth guard called');
    if (this.storage.retrieveAccessToken() && this.storage.retrieveAuthToken()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('RouterStateSnapshot values', state);
        this.router.navigate(['/auth/login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});
        return false;
    }
```

Then you can use your returnUrl as the path to navigate if authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of that redirecting is that after bypass the auth login.
You must be making another redirect inside `/dashboard`.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
```

Should be changed to:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl,  { skipLocationChange: true });
```